# Как считать определенную строку из файла?

Tags: java, строки, файлы

> Текстовый файл содержит произвольное количество строк. Каждая строка – это слова, разделенные пробелами. Ввести номер строки. В указанной строке отсортировать слова по возрастанию, записать результат в файл. Вывести на консоль исходный и преобразованный файлы.

Comment: Для решения этой задачи обычно используется два пути - или читать по одной строке, считая их, или прочитать весь текстовый файл в список строк методом вроде ReadAllLines и выбрать нужную строку.

Comment: Сортировать по Алфавиту?

Answer (score 1):

Сортирую по алфавиту, если надо другое - скажите

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String str = new String(
                Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Test.txt")));
        System.out.println("Исходный файл:\n" + str + "\n");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите номер строки:");
        int lineNumber = 0;
        try {
            lineNumber = Integer.valueOf(s.nextLine()) - 1;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        }
        s.close();
        String line = "";
        try {
            line = str.split("\n")[lineNumber];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.err.println("Такой строки нет в файле");
            return;
        }
        String words[] = line.split(" ");
        
        
        java.util.List<String> l = Arrays.asList(words);
        l.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });
        System.out.println("\nСлова:");
        for (String string : l) {
            char[] cs = string.toCharArray();
            String ns = "";
            for (char c : cs) {
                if(Character.isUpperCase(Character.toUpperCase(c)))
                    ns += c;
            }
            if(!ns.isEmpty())
                System.out.println("> " + ns);
        }
}
```

Файл:

```
Задача такая: Текстовый файл содержит произвольное количество строк.
Каждая строка – это слова, разделенные пробелами.
Ввести номер строки.
В указанной строке отсортировать слова по возрастанию, записать результат в файл.
Вывести на консоль исходный и преобразованный файлы.
```

Ввод:

```
1
```

Вывод:

```
Иходный файл:
Задача такая: Текстовый файл содержит произвольное количество строк.
Каждая строка – это слова, разделенные пробелами.
Ввести номер строки.
В указанной строке отсортировать слова по возрастанию, записать результат в файл.
Вывести на консоль исходный и преобразованный файлы.

Введите номер строки:
<ввод>

Слова:
> Задача
> Текстовый
> количество
> произвольное
> содержит
> строк
> такая
> файл
```